# Proving that minimal blocks have a vertex of degree 2

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

I'm trying to show that if we have a graph G that is a minimal block with at least 4 vertices, that one the vertices must have degree 2.

We have defined a minimal block as a 2-connected graph such that that the removal of any edge e results in a subgraph G-e that is not 2 connected.

I'm assuming that all the vertices in the graph are of at least degree 3 and trying to find a contradiction. I'm using the theorem that the graph is two connected if and only if any vertices lie on a common cycle. 
Any help is much appreciated as I think I'm getting lost in different cases of the graph. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple proof is possible when you know that every 2-connected graph
has an ear decomposition.

Let $G$ be our minimal 2-connected graph.
If the ear decomposition has only one step, then $G$ is a cycle,
so it has a vertex of degree 2.

Otherwise let $P$ be the last added ear.

If $P$ has more than one edge, it has a vertex of degree 2, that is also in $G$.
Otherwise $P$ is an edge $e$ and $G-e$ is still 2-connected (since every
step in the ear decomposition is 2-connected), which contradicts the minimality of $G$.